# editing time at PHP

Tags: php

How do i add 8 hours from a time value taken from an array?

FROM:

```
$time = "Thu Jan 12 02:01:17 +0000 2012";
```

TO:

```
$time = "Thu Jan 12 10:01:17 +0000 2012";
```

Answer (score 3):

There are few ways of doing so, simple and less accurate method:

```
echo date('+8 hours', strtotime($time));
```

More advanced method using [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
//create DateTime instance
$date = new DateTime($time);
//set custom timezone
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
//add 8 hours
$date->modify('+8 hours');
//print formatted datetime string
print $date->format('D M d H:i:s O Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime class:

```
$time = new DateTime("Thu Jan 12 02:01:17 +0000 2012");
echo $time->modify("+8 hours")->format("D M d H:i:s O Y");
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
It can also do timezone manipulations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$time = "Thu Jan 12 02:01:17 +0000 2012";
echo date('D M d H:i:s +0000 Y', strtotime($time.' +8 hours'))."\n";
```

Comment: You could have written `+8 hours` insted of `60 * 60 * 8`. That makes it a little bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$hours= date("D M d H:i:s +0000 Y",strtotime("Thu Jan 12 02:01:17 +0000 2012 +8 hours"));

echo $hours;

?>
```

[demo](http://codepad.org/3nW7YqV4)